# How to add a className to single .map item?

Tags: reactjs, dom, jsx

I want to add className to a .map item, but only for the one which is clicked.

Tried useState ( {state ? "class" : ""} ) but it added class for all items inside my loop.
I also tried useRef but I learned that useRef does not cause re-render so result didn't update on screen.

example code:

```
    {posts.map((post)=> {
      return (
        <div className=`PLACE FOR CLASS` key={post.id}>
        {post.title}
        <button onClick={()=> onclick event to add class}>add</button>
        </div>
      )
    })}
```

So what is the way to add class only for item which is clicked in this case? ( I think I need to use Key but don't know how )

Comment: Does `post` have any indication of whether it is clicked or not?

Comment: I change postId state to get id of clicked post. ( to edit the post later )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to add this information to the main state (`posts`) you can create a separate list of selected ids, it'll be something like this (assuming you're using function components)

```
const [selectedPosts, setSelectedPosts]=useState([]);
...
{posts.map((post)=> {
  return (
    <div className={selectedPosts.includes(post.id) && "myClass"} key={post.id}>
    {post.title}
    <button onClick={()=> {setSelectedPosts(s => [...s, post.id])}}>add</button>
    </div>
  )
})}
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I wanted!